# Sort all pivot tables in a workbook using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, pivot-table

I am trying to sort all pivot tables across many sheets using the following code:

```
Sub sortpivots()

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables().PivotFields("name").AutoSort _
       xlAscending, "Min of start", ActiveSheet.PivotTables(). _
       PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1)



End Sub
```

I have made a macro but it is long and ugly, there must be a way to target all the pivot tables at once. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use For Each to walk through the PivotTables collection. Of course you can't reference all at once like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use to For Each loops, the first to cycle through the Activeworkbook's worksheets, the second to loop through the pivot tables in each worksheet:

```
Sub sortpivots()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim pvt As Excel.PivotTable

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pvt In ws.PivotTables
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables().PivotFields("name").AutoSort _
            xlAscending, "Min of start", ActiveSheet.PivotTables(). _
            PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1)
    Next pvt
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This was the right answer, however my code in the foreach loop was wrong. I ended up manually sorting the pivot tables and putting in a refresh button in that refreshes the sheets with the pivot tables. Thank you for your input though.